# C++ copy vector of objects to another

Tags: c++, object, vector

I want to copy to vectors with the same size and same type one to another but after printing the value it seems like it doesn't work correctly or it doesn't want to copy all pointers to data in each object. Thanks for help

Here is code:

```
std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles(2);
std::vector<Vehicle> vehiclesCopy(2);

vehicles[0].setX_pos(3);

for(int i=0;i<vehicles.size();i++)
    vehiclesCopy.push_back(vehicles[i]);

cout<<vehicles[0].getX_pos()<<endl;
cout<<vehiclesCopy[0].getX_pos()<<endl;
```

Output:

3

0

Here is the Vehicle code

```
class Vehicle
{
private:
    unsigned int x_pos,y_pos,velocity;
    char type;
public:
    void vehicle(char           inType,
                unsigned int    inX_pos,
                unsigned int    inY_pos,
                unsigned int    inVelocity)
                {
                    type=inType;
                    x_pos=inX_pos;
                    y_pos=inY_pos;
                    velocity=inVelocity;
        }
    unsigned int getMaxPassengers(){
        return maxPassengers;
    }
    unsigned int getX_pos(){
            return x_pos;
        }
    unsigned int getY_pos(){
            return y_pos;
        }
    unsigned int getVelocity(){
            return velocity;
        }
    char getType(){
            return type;
        }
    void setX_pos(unsigned int input){
            x_pos=input;
        }
    void setY_pos(unsigned int input){
            y_pos=input;
        }
    void setVelocity(unsigned int input){
            velocity=input;
        }
    void setType(char input){
        type=input;
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. Define a copy constrictor for Vehicle (as you have only simple types line `int` and `char`, the default copy constrictor is enough);

2. std::vector<Vehicle> vehiclesCopy(vehicles);

Comment: @SergeyAleksandrovich no, that'd be irrelevant. See *rule of zero*.

Comment: sorry for being too fast in assuming the problem is in code you didnt show (before the edit), but in any case questions about problems with code should present a mcve. Without seeing the definition of `Vehicle` more things could go wrong than what is apparent from the snippet you posted first

Comment: @molbdnilo when you want to create vector it's easier to don't have a constructor with arguments,

Comment: not sure, but maybe molbdnilo refered to the constructor of `std::vector`, see my just added PS in the answer

Comment: A vector's `push_back()` member function appends an element i.e. it increases the size of the vector.   The first two elements of `vehiclesCopy`  will be the ones created when the vector is created (both vehicles default-initialised).   The third and fourth elements will be copies of the first and second elements of `vehicles`, respectively.

Comment: oh sorry i didnt read it correct

Comment: @Itsmycode It's only "easier" if default-constructed objects make sense, and they rarely do. Yours is one example.

Answer (score 5):

You create two vectors with size 2. Then you push all elements from one vector to the other. You now have one unmodified vector and the other vector with 4 elements. Pushing two elements at the end wont have any effect on the first element (the one you print).

To copy vectors use simple assignment:

```
vehiclesCopy = vehicles;
```

Or if you want to use a loop (why would you?), assuming they both have correct size (they do in your example):

```
for(int i=0;i<vehicles.size();i++) {
    vehiclesCopy[i] = vehicles[i];
}
```

PS: this answer isnt the whole truth. If `vehiclesCopy` is really just a copy of `vehicles` you should not first construct an empty vector and then copy it, but instead use the right constructor. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for details (overload (6) is your friend here).

Comment: I have tried your solution but it doesn't work also, the output is the same as before

Comment: @Itsmycode what is the meaning of "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: @Itsmycode if you post your code eg [here](https://wandbox.org/) i can look at it. If it is a new problem, maybe open a new question

Comment: it means that the output is still the same, i have tried this std::vector<Vehicle> vehiclesCopy(vehicle); and also vehiclesCopy = vehicles; but output is still 3 0

Comment: @Itsmycode works as expected here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZEAWi0DNfoJ0nBvl you must have some other problem in your code

Comment: yes now its working, I just forgot to rebuild it, thanks